# How to use StreamBuilder to listen for a document change in Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

My goal is to refactor the code below to use a StreamBuilder.  It has been suggested that I could improve my code even further by using a StreamBuilder but after a few days of trying I honestly can't figure out what to do or where to begin.

I want the user interface and the Firestore database to react to user taps on a switch tile.  The boolean value in Firestore should toggle when the user clicks the switch and the switch tile user interface should update accordingly.

The code below works just fine but it doesn't use a StreamBuilder.
Thanks in advance for any help.

```
class InterestsFitnessTile extends StatefulWidget {


  const InterestsFitnessTile({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<InterestsFitnessTile> createState() => _InterestsFitnessTileState();
}

class _InterestsFitnessTileState extends State<InterestsFitnessTile> {
  bool isFitnessActive = true;
  final String? currentSignedInUserID = Auth().currentUser?.uid;
  Future<void> _updateFitnessSetting() async {
    await Auth()
        .userInterestsSettingsReference
        .doc(currentSignedInUserID)
        .update({
      AuthString.fitness: isFitnessActive,
    });

    setState(() {
      isFitnessActive = !isFitnessActive;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SwitchListTileSliver(
      icon: Provider.of<InterestsPageProvider>(context).isFitnessTurnedOff
          ? Icons.thumb_down
          : Icons.thumb_up,
      onChanged: (value) {
        final provider = Provider.of<InterestsPageProvider>(
          context,
          listen: false,
        );
        provider.updateFitnessSettings(isOn: value);
        _updateFitnessSetting();
      },
      subTitle: Provider.of<InterestsPageProvider>(context).isFitnessTurnedOff
          ? const Text(
        SettingsPageString.fitnessOff,
      )
          : const Text(
        SettingsPageString.fitnessOn,
      ),
      title: SettingsPageString.fitness,
      value: Provider.of<InterestsPageProvider>(context).isFitnessTurnedOff,
    );
  }
}


class InterestsPageProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

  bool _currentFitness = false;
  bool get isFitnessTurnedOff => _currentFitness == true;
  void updateFitnessSettings({required bool isOn}) {
    _currentFitness = !_currentFitness;
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you include the code of `InterestsPageProvider`?

Comment: @enzo Code updated to include the InterestsPageProvider.  Thanks for reviewing my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two examples in which I have used Streambuilder:
Example 1:

```
class Messages extends StatelessWidget {
const Messages({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("chat")
      .orderBy("createdAt", descending: true)
      .snapshots(),
  builder: (ctx, snapShot) {
    if (snapShot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    } else {
      final chatDocs = snapShot.data!.docs;
      return ListView.builder(
        reverse: true,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => MessageBubble(
          chatDocs[i]['text'],
          chatDocs[i]['userName'],
          chatDocs[i]['userId'] == currentUser,
          chatDocs[i]['userImg'],
        ),
        itemCount: chatDocs.length,
      );
    }
  },
);}}
```

Example 2:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => CarsProvider(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          builder: (ctx, snapShot) =>
              snapShot.hasData ? const HomePage() : const UserAuth(),
        ),
        routes: {
          HomePage.routeName: (_) => const HomePage(),
          SearchPage.routeName: (_) => const SearchPage(),
          SearchedItemDetail.routeName: (_) => const SearchedItemDetail(),
          ForgotPassword.routeName: (_) => const ForgotPassword(),
          AddItem.routeName: (_) => const AddItem(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to coding so I am still working through your examples to try to apply it to my code but I at least wanted to respond so that you knew that your attempt to help me was appreciated.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: I hope It will help :)